# responsive background-image css code

Tags: html, css

This the code that existed with the template I purchased.

```
.punch_text03 {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 40px 0px;
    background-color: #3398d4;
}
```

Instead of the `padding size` and `background color` I am trying use a `background-image` that is 1920px by 200px. I have tried this but it doesn't work

```
.punch_text03 {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    background: url('../images/bg11.jpg');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:contain;
    background-position:center;
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on "it doesn't work"? Does the image appear at all, or does it not appear in the way you'd like?

Comment: Post your HTML code and a fiddle! That would help a lot

Comment: look at dvmark.com/media-design/powerpoint-presentations.html on a desktop. at the bottom is blue background image that reads free web page edits, then view in mobile phone

Answer (score 1):

when I checked it in inspection the selector looks like this

```
.punch_text03{
float: left;
width: 100%;
padding: 40px 0px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-color: #0a70e3;
background: url('../images/bg11.jpg');
```

Try adding

```
background-size:cover;
```

That works.

if you only want it happen on phones, use a media query

```
@media screen and (max-width:768px){
    .punch_text03{
        background-size:cover;
    }
}
```

Should solve your problem.